# How to detect if group is deleted from user in Okta

Tags: okta, okta-api

I am trying to get deleted groups from user via rest api in Okta.
I cant see any anything which gives me information of deleted groups from user in Okta.
How can i detect if group is removed from user in okta.

Comment: Are you able to expand a little bit on what you are trying to do here?  Are you trying to get alerted when a group is removed from a user, or just check to see if a user belongs to a group?

Comment: I am trying to get user details whose group is removed from rest api.